# dynamiclly allocate and free in C

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, free

```
void* heap = malloc(100);
char *c = heap;
strcpy(c, "Terence");
printf("heap = %s\n", heap);
free(heap);
heap = malloc(100);
printf("heap = %s\n", heap);
```

the output is:

```
heap = Terence
heap =
```

That is what I expect, but now I have a far more complex code, the structure is similar to the above, but the output is like:

```
heap = "Terence"
heap = "  ren  "
```

something like that.

It seems heap has not been cleaned up?

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The region of memory allocated by `malloc` has an indeterminate initial value.

From the C Standard (emphasis mine):

> (c99, 7.20.3.3p2) "The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and **whose value is indeterminate***."

Use `calloc` or `memset` after `malloc` to have a determinate value.

Comment: Or, in the case of a buffer for a string, just set the first byte to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Malloc does not implicitly zero out the allocated memory. You need to cell either calloc or memset for this purpose:

```
heap = malloc(100);
memset(heap, 0, 100);
```

or

```
heap = calloc(100, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you free any memory block you should always set the pointer variable to `NULL`, because the memory is no longer accessible.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `void free( void* ptr );` to release a previously allocated memory block, you use the pointer variable as an argument to the free function. The function only reads the pointer variable, and does not automatically set it to NULL for you.

Therefore, it is up to you to set that variable to NULL, so that other code you have written, which may depend on that variable, will be dealing with a NULL pointer, instead of a memory address that looks OK but points to memory that cannot be accessed any longer.